# I'm having troubles trying to vertical align a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hello I'm trying to align the "container2" div to bottom of "cointainer" but I'm having troubles and I dont know where, any help?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

     <div id="container2">
         <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
/*Colors*/
background-color:rgb(129, 159, 255);
/*Size Box*/
width:400px;
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto; }

 #container2{
 /*Colors*/
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 /*Size Box*/
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 padding:20px;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:auto;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current structure you would have to position the child with `position:absolute`.

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/3/)**

**CSS**

```
#container{
    /*Colors*/
    background-color:rgb(129, 159, 255);

    /*Size Box*/
    width:400px;
    height:200px;

    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    position: relative;


}

#container2{
    /*Colors*/
    background-color:black;
    color:white;

    /*Size Box*/
    width:50%;
    height:50%;

    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -25%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#container { position: relative; }
#container2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Or simply use tables

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/1/)

```
#container {
    background-color:rgb(129, 159, 255);
    display: table-cell;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#container2 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    /*Size Box*/
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set margin-top (you know both heights) or using positioning, I´ve chosen second variant.

```
#container {postition: relative}
#container2 {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 25%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set position relative to container2

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/4/)

```
#container2{
    /*Colors*/
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;

    /*Size Box*/
    width:50%;
    height:50%;

    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use position absolute; you can do this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4GT4/5/)

### css

```
#container{
    text-align:center;
}
#container:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#container2{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```